# Evaluation of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {x^{-n}}{n}$

Tags: summation

I wanted to evaluate

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {2^{-n}}{n}
$$

And noticed that for any base it has a pattern, so now I want to know how to evaluate

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {x^{-n}}{n}
$$

I don't have any approach. The result is logarithmic. If any problems occur $\forall x$ then I want a solution for valid $x$ values.

Comment: Replace $x$ by $1/y$ and recognize the Taylor expansion of $-\log(1-y)$.

Comment: You can try differentiating term by term, summing the resultant series and integrating the resulting formula (being careful about the constant of integration)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One alternative way, that generalizes to a wide range of similar questions, is to differentiate with respect to $x$ under the sum:
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {x^{-n}}{n}\\
f'(x)=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{-n-1}
$$
which is just a geometric series, which can be evaluated, and subsequently integrated to retrieve $f(x)$. You'll need to fix the constant of integration, which can be set by what happens as $x\to\infty$.

Answer (score 6):

Substitute the $y = -1/x$ and you'll notice than this is a Taylor series for logarithm ($-\ln(1+y)$):

Also:
$$
\ln(1+y) = y - \frac{y^2}{2} + \frac{y^3}{3} - \cdots
$$

Comment: @monhawk - very clever solution. a minor typo but you probably meant to say $\ln(1+y)$.

Answer (score 4):

We want to compute the following sum:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{nz^n},\;\;\;\; z\in\mathbb C\;.
$$
We immediately see that $|z|>1$, in order to have absolute convergence.

We recall first two results:

$\bullet\;\;$First:
$$
\log(1+z)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{z^n}{n},\;\;\;\forall |z|<1
$$
$\bullet\;\;$Second:
$$
\prod_{n=0}^{+\infty}\left(1+z^{2^{n}}\right)=
\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}z^{n}=\frac{1}{1-z},\;\;\;\forall |z|<1
$$
The last one can be proved, showing by induction that $\prod_{k=0}^{N}\left(1+z^{2^{k}}\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{2^{N+1}-1}z^{k}$.

Ok:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{nz^n}=&
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^n\\
=&\underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{2k+1}\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^{2k+1}-
\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{2k}\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^{2k}}_{\log\left(1+\frac{1}{z}\right)}+
2\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{2k}\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^{2k}\\
=&\log\left(1+\frac{1}{z}\right)+
\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k}\left(\frac{1}{z^2}\right)^{k}\\
=&\log\left(1+\frac{1}{z}\right)+
\log\left(1+\frac{1}{z^2}\right)+\cdots\\
=&\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{z^{2^n}}\right)\\
=&\log\left(\prod_{n=0}^{+\infty}\left(1+\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^{2^n}\right)\right)\\
=&\log\left(\frac{z}{z-1}\right)
\end{align*}

If otherwise we want to sum

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{nz^n}
$$
it's simpler:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{nz^n}&
=-\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^n\\
&=-\log\left(1+\frac{1}{z}\right)\\
&=\log\left(\frac{z}{z+1}\right).
\end{align*}